# Maintaining ColXpr to a MatrixXf across conservativeResize

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to maintain a variable that references the first column of an Eigen::MatrixXf across a conservative resize.

The `ColXpr c` looks like it is invalidated when `MatrixXf m` is resized and cannot be reassigned. I can see how this could protect me from mistakes but I don't understand what I should do so that `c` gives me the first column of the new `m`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf m = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(4,2);
    Eigen::MatrixXf::ColXpr c = m.col(0);

    std::cout << m << std::endl;
    //   0.680375  0.823295
    //  -0.211234 -0.604897
    //   0.566198 -0.329554
    //    0.59688  0.536459
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    //   0.680375
    //  -0.211234
    //   0.566198
    //    0.59688

    m.conservativeResize(3, Eigen::NoChange);

    std::cout << m << std::endl;
    //   0.680375  0.823295
    //  -0.211234 -0.604897
    //   0.566198 -0.329554
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    //  1.4013e-45
    //           0
    //  1.4013e-45
    //           0


    c = m.col(0); // <<<<< This cores with the Eigen Warning
    // Assertion `rows() == other.rows() && cols() == other.cols()' failed.

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen expression types like `ColXpr` are intended to be used as temporaries, constructed and destroyed in a single line. Their main purpose is to avoid unnecessary copying -- in the `ColXpr` case, by aliasing data from the original array.

The aliasing is an implementation detail, NOT a user-facing feature. You shouldn't rely on `ColXpr` being updated *even if you just modify the original matrix*, let alone resize it.

If you want something that will give you the first column of the matrix, all the time, that thing is `m.col(0)`. You can wrap that in a function if you like.